# Nested div element overflowing flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this html page:

```
    <div class="header"></div>

        <div id="content-meta-wrapper">
            <div id="content">
               <!-- with several nested divs -->            
            </div>
            
            <div id="bookmarks">
                <!-- with some anchor elements -->
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="footer">    
        </div> 

        
    </div>
```

With the following css style:

```
#flex-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    order: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #content-meta-wrapper {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: row;
  }
}

#content-meta-wrapper {
    order: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
  #content-meta-wrapper {
      flex-direction: column;
  }
}


.footer {
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#content {
    width: 73%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    order: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}

#bookmarks {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 20%;
    order: 2;
}
```

Since `#content` has a lot of divs and p nested, its height is really high and it's overflowing the parent div (`#content-meta-wrapper`). I've tried with `overflow: hidden`, `auto` and `scroll`. I've tried also with `min-height`. What I'm trying to achive is that `#flex-container` occupies 100%  of the screen (100vh), and all of its children are visible on the viewport. I want `#content-meta-wrapper` to occupy most of the screen, but without giving it a fixed `height`. Especially, I'd like `#content` to not overflow `#content-meta-wrapper` without giving it a fixed `height` (for responsiveness purposes), so that the user can scroll only within the `#content` div, without having to scroll the whole page. Is it possible to achieve this?

```css
#flex-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    order: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #content-meta-wrapper {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: row;
  }
}

#content-meta-wrapper {
    order: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
  #content-meta-wrapper {
      flex-direction: column;
  }
}


.footer {
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#content {
    width: 73%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    order: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}

#bookmarks {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 20%;
    order: 2;
}
```

```html
<body>
        
    <div id="flex-container">

        <div class="header">menu</div>

            <div id="content-meta-wrapper">
                <div id="content">
                   <div>content</div>   
                   <div>content</div>   
                   <div>veeery long content</div>
                   <div>content</div>   
                   <div>content</div>   
                   <div>veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long conten, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content, veeery long content</div>
                </div>
                
                <div id="bookmarks">
                    <a>bookmark no. 1</a>
                    <a>bookmark no. 2</a>
                    <a>bookmark no. 3</a>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="footer"> a simple footer </div> 

            
        </div>  

</body>
```